# How to login with Facebook in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-4, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to make an application where the user has to login with Facebook. I am using the laravel 4 framework. Since Facebook doesn't allow using development in localhost I have deployed my code in Heroku and tried it there. There is no problem with the app domain and the site url. I have successfully come to the redirect url. In my code the redirect url is the `getFacebooklogin()`.

But the problem is in the redirect url. I cannot show the user information using the graph api. Heroku doesn't show what the error is. It just says that there is an error. I have checked Heroku logs. I still haven't found out what the error is.

This is the code of my controller.

```
<?php
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
class SiteController extends BaseController{
    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

    public function __construct(){
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('id','secret');
    }
    public function getIndex(){
        $this->layout->content = View::make('sites.home');
    }

    public function getFacebooklogin(){
        $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(url('site/facebooklogin'));
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
        $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
        dd($graphObject);
    }
}
```

Here is the code of my view

```
<?php
    session_start();

    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;

    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(url('site/facebooklogin'));
?>
<a href="<?php echo $helper->getLoginUrl();?>">Sign in with Facebook</a>
```

Here is the [link](http://boolean-retrieval-2.herokuapp.com) for my project.

Comment: Facebook does allow development on localhost. You just need to use an alias like 'sites.local' and have a self-signed SSL certificate.